# Google Spreadsheet Populating Cells in Other Sheet Based on Value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, excel-indirect

Am new to Google Docs, but have to create a cumulative report of comments that are flagged as positive or negative.  I have 6 worksheets that ideally would populate to a single report, but I could create 6 individual reports for now.

In the source sheet, ColA is a numeric code identifying the category.  Col B is the category description; Col C are the notes from one person; Col D is the code to identify it as positive or negative;  Cols E and F are the notes from a 2nd person; G/H from a 3rd, etc.

The report sheet needs to transpose the vertical comments by category with the positive comments for all persons for the first category in Col G, the negative comments for the 1st category in Col H, etc for all 6 categories.

I was able to manually create this report using the following formula to extract the Positive comments from column C:

```
QUERY(EntrySheet1!C5:D15;"select * where D='P'")
```

But, it's pretty tedious to copy the formula laterally and vertically to accommodate all 6 categories and all 6 note takers.

So, my questions are whether or not there is an easier way to extract the information the way I need to report it.  Also, is there a way to use something like Excel's Indirect function where I could use the concatenate function to build the formulas and the Indirect to evaluate that function.  My thought here is that I could have an entry cell where I would identify which cumulative report I wanted to view by simply updating the cell.  An alternative would be to load the data into an array and use a script to populate a static cumulative report.   Real-time updating with formulas would be ideal, but creating a static report that is created from a script is acceptable.  My biggest concern is the manual effort to update the formulas since they are sheet specific.

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Spreadsheet INDIRECT function.

See the [Google spreadsheets function list](https://support.google.com/drive/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=25273&page=table.cs&tab=1240292):

```
INDIRECT(reference) 

Returns the reference specified by a text string. This function can also be used to
return the area of a corresponding string. Reference is a reference to a cell or an
area (in text form) for which to return the contents.
```

You might be able to feed the results of indirect into your query.